# MariaDB JSON Functions with Arrays

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

I have JSON arrays stored as strings in a MariaDB table. I want to return the rows when certain key-values are present anywhere in the array.

I performed the following test....

```
set @json='[{"name":"Albert","state":"IL"},{"name":"John","state":"CA"}]'
```

Executed the following query ...

```
select json_value(@json,'$[0].name')='Albert'
```

It got me the desired result which is...

```
1
```

Even the following query also gave me the same result(may be '*' is treated as the first element)...

```
select json_value(@json,'$[*].name')='Albert'
```

But when I provide the second name("John") in the condition, I do not get any result...

```
select json_value(@json,'$[*].name')='John'
```

Result...

```
0
```

So my observation is that when we provide the array index the "json_value" function is able to return the desired result.

Is there a way where I can avoid specifying the array index and search the desired key-value?

Comment: Try [JSON_SEARCH](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json_search/), see [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=4620e2cf592fda2a9dd788ec5f98962a).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As commented by @dbfiddle I tried using [JSON_SEARCH](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json_search/) function.

Here is what I tried to get the desired result.

```
create table label_test(labels VARCHAR(1000));

insert into label_test values ('[{"name":"Albert","state":"IL"},{"name":"John","state":"CA"}]');

select * from label_test where JSON_SEARCH(labels,'all','John') like '"$[%].name"';
```

The result is the whole row as expected.

```
[{"name":"Albert","state":"IL"},{"name":"John","state":"CA"}]
```